# cordova Error in Success TypeError: Cannot read property 'filesystemName' of null

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugin-file

I've got an app where the following logic fails every **2nd** time I run the app on Android :

```
 window.requestFileSystem( LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, 
                    function( fs ) {
                      console.log('Success!', fs);
                    }, 
                    function( e ) {
                        console.error('Fail!', e);
                    }
                );
```

The error I get is :

> cordova.js:312 Error in Success callbackId: File1306990920 :
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'filesystemName' of null

Cordova.js line 312 is a generic catch in the `callbackFromNative` function.

Has anyone come across this?

What is the remedy?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Just delete the `<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />` from the config.xml, or change `"Compatibility"` for `"Internal"`, seems to be responsible to add the null value to the array response, that mention below

---

I'm using the cordova file plugin with Ionic2, if is not your case maybe this can give you some highlights.

My trace of this error takes me to `.../plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/fileSystems-roots.js`, that Maps of fsName -> FileSystem.

This makes me thinks that is a bug, but I'm not sure even how to report it.

Anyways, the problem is that the response to map contains a null object, as you can see in the copy of the response below:

```
[
    null
    , {"fullPath":"/","filesystemName":"persistent","isDirectory":true,"nativeURL":"file:...","filesystem":1,"isFile":false,"name":""}
    , {"fullPath":"/","filesystemName":"content","isDirectory":true,"nativeURL":"content:...","filesystem":1,"isFile":false,"name":""}
    , {"fullPath":"/","filesystemName":"assets","isDirectory":true,"nativeURL":"file:...","filesystem":1,"isFile":false,"name":""}
    , {"fullPath":"/","filesystemName":"cache","isDirectory":true,"nativeURL":"file:...","filesystem":1,"isFile":false,"name":""}
]
```

Again, I'm using ionic2 and if is your case too, you can use the File plugin directly, following the next steps:

0- Install the plugin (If you are getting this error I suppose you already have done this step)

1- Import the plugin as provider in you module, something like

```
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';

@NgModule({
    ...
    , providers: [
        ...
        , File
        ...
    ]
    ...
})
```

2- Add the plugin as provider in your component

```
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';

export class FileCreatorComponent {
    constructor(..., private file: File, ...) { }
```

3- Use it according to this page [Ionic2 Native file plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/), for example to create (and overwrite if exist) you can do this:

```
createFile() {
    var filePath= this.file.externalRootDirectory + 'Download/';
    //var filePath= 'file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/'; If the first doesn't work you can put this path, NOT RECOMMENDED, because the first should work
    var fileName= 'newOne.txt';

    this.file.writeFile(filePath, fileName, 'Lorem ipsum', { replace: true } )
                .then(() => {
                    console.log('File created');
                });
}
```